# Помогите с логикой оплаты и вывода данных о ней

Tags: php, база-данных, логика, интернет-магазин

Есть сайт, предлагающий некие услуги как товар. Пользователь ходит по страницам и вдруг находит нужную ему услугу. Нажимает "купить". Допустим он уже зарегистрирован/авторизован на сайте. После нажатия на "купить" он переходит на страницу оплаты, где выбирает способ оплаты, доставки итд. Оплачивает услугу. Далее в его личном кабинете должна отображаться история его покупок, оказанных (не оказанных, но купленных) услуг.

**Вопрос такой:** как привязать эту оплаченную услугу к этому пользователю, для того чтобы вывести ее название (цену, еще какие-то характеристики) в личном кабинете этого пользователя?

Если просто добавить поля в БД под какой-то ИД этих услуг, то я же не знаю сколько именно услуг пользователь купит. Т.е я не могу же просто добавить ему 100500 полей и чтоб они заполнялись по мере приобретения услуг. Также я не могу просто добавить ОДНО поле, по тем же причинам (как мне выводить данные из 1 поля, если там, к примеру, десятки услуг).

Comment: Погуглите в сторону: "Связь один ко многим". Думаю это то что Вам нужно.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Похоже это то что надо. А то даже не знал как в гугле это обозвать.